# Every countable metrizable spaces can be embedded in reals

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I want to prove that every countable metrizable spaces can be embedded in reals, using that the irrational numbers $\mathbb{P}$ are homeomorphic to the Baire space $\omega^\omega$. Let $(X, d)$ be a countable metric space. Fix an enumeration $(x_n)$ of $X$. Since $A := \{d(x, y) \mid x, y \in X\} \cup \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} + \pi \subset \mathbb{P}$ are unbounded countable dense linearly ordered sets, we can find an order isomorphism $f\colon A \to \mathbb{Q} + \pi$ which can be extended to a unique homeomorphism $F\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $g_n\colon X \to \mathbb{I}$ be defined as $g_n(x) = F(d(x, x_n))$. $\{g_n\}$ separates points from closed sets and $X$ is $T_0$, so $g\colon X \to \mathbb{P}^\omega$ defined as $[g(x)](n) = g_n(x)$ is a homeomorphic embedding. Since $\mathbb{P}^\omega \sim (\omega^\omega)^\omega \sim \omega^\omega \sim \mathbb{P} \subset \mathbb{R}$, we are done. Is this right?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is universal for all countable metric spaces.

Comment: $\Bbb P$ is conventional for the irrationals (at least in topology). $\Bbb P \cup \Bbb Q=\Bbb R$ is a nice identity.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for the edit. Yes, it can be proven with this fact using similar argument once more. After embedding $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$, extend the order isomorphism $X \cup \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ once again to a homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}$. Actually I'm proving this to prove the universality of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: For that just use the scattering sequence; we're left with a countable ordinal with possible remaining $\Bbb Q$ core (no isolated points means homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$). Countable ordinals order embed into $\Bbb Q$ by order theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A countable metric space embeds into $2^\omega=\{0,1\}^\omega$ via a countable clopen base (use the characteristic functions of the countable clopen base). And $2^\omega$ trivially  embeds into $\Bbb P \simeq \omega^\omega$ and $\Bbb R$ (middle third set).

Comment: Wow. That's much simpler.

Comment: @Ris Sure. That's why I posted it.

Comment: @Ris It does assume that you know countable metric spaces are zero-dimensional, but that's easy to see.

Comment: Yes. There are only countably many possible distances so we can take a base of open balls which are also closed balls.

Comment: @Ris precisely. And a countable metric space is trivially second countable so we thin out the clopen base to a countable one.

Comment: And of course the same argument shows that any zero-dimensional separable metric space embeds in $\mathbb R$. And a much deeper argument shows that every $n$-dimensional separable metric space embeds in $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$ if I remember right from a class I took long ago.

Comment: @bof Yes via the classical embedding theorem (Nöbeling's theorem IIRC).

Comment: @bof yes, that can even be slightly improved, zero dimensional separable metrizable spaces embed into $\omega^\omega\cong\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ and the $n$ dimensional ones into the subspace of $\Bbb R^{2n+1}$ consisting of points with at most $n$ rational coordinates (one of the so called Nöbeling spaces)